# Windows XP Microsoft Update web page loop

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, activex

When I visit http://www.update.microsoft.com/ I get the warning about a blocked add-on 'Microsoft Update'.  (Running Windows XP SP2.)

This is fine, but when I then let the ActiveX control run the page reloads and the same warning comes up again; no matter how many times I allow the ActiveX control, I always get the warning.

How can I tell Windows I want to run this ActiveX control instead of having it being permanently blocked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to go to `Internet Options` and then look for the `Security` Tab.

Click on the `Trusted Sites` icon and add `http://*.update.microsoft.com` to it. This should allow ActiveX controls to run fine.

Also, it is possible that you have blocked the Windows Update control from the Addins section, so you may want to double check there.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks Wil, adding a trusted site now works. I will accept your answer, but I don't think I worded my question correctly. What I really wanted to know is why wont Windows accept that I want to run the ActiveX control instead of blocking it all the time? (It wasn't in the Add-ons section). Adding a trusted site is in this case (IMO) a last-resort workaround because I don't know the real answer to my real question. But thanks anyway Wil, it's got me over one hurdle!